# whats the correct way to "shim" in systemjs?

Tags: amd, systemjs

Sorry for the obfuscated question, I'll elaborate my problem. I am currently developing a single page app in Aurelia, and I found a lib I want to try out: https://github.com/hootsuite/grid. I did the normal jspm routine:

```
jspm install github:hootsuite/grid
```

which installs successfully and adds the following to the systemjs config:

```
map: {
    "hootsuite/grid": "github:hootsuite/grid@1.0.0",
```

The package file looks like this:

```
define(["github:hootsuite/grid@1.0.0/src/gridList.js"], function(main) {
    return main;
});
```

Which enables me import the module as expected:

```
import * as grid from 'hootsuite/grid';
```

So far so good, but the js file referenced by the module is not the one I am interested in (src/gridList.js), the src folder also contains a jquery plugin named "jquery.gridlist.js" which is the file I actually want to resolve. I managed to "fix/hack" it by adding an additional AMD module definition in the module file (grid@1.0.0.js):

```
define('gridlist', ["github:hootsuite/grid@1.0.0/src/gridList.js"], function(main) {
  return main;
});

define(["github:hootsuite/grid@1.0.0/src/jquery.gridList.js", "github:hootsuite/grid@1.0.0/src/gridList.js"], function(main) {
  return main;
});
```

This is not a viable solution because the jspm_modules are not a part of source-control, thus it will have to be patched manually for every dev. So, whats the best approach for this type of problem? Or which features am I missing out on which removes the problem entirely?